# Find matrix $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ first rotates $2\pi/3$ rad (counterclockwise) then reflects across line $x2 = -x1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I know that the answer is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I am not sure on the steps to get to this point.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried matrix multiplication with the first matrix being [0,-1,-1,0] and the second being [cos(4pi/3),-sin(4pi/3),sin(4pi/3),cos(4pi/3)]

Comment: Ok, so what matrix does the rotation?

Comment: The second matrix

Comment: Also, are you sure you inputed the answer correctly?

Comment: That was the answer my professor gave me. What answer did you get?

Answer (score 0):

So, the first thing I would note is that matrix multiplication performs operations in the order the matrices are multiplied. That is, you need to perform a rotation and a reflection on an input vector $\vec{x}$. That is
$$
M \vec{x} = Ref Rot(2\pi/3)  \vec{x}
$$

We know the rotation matrix, $Rot(\theta)$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And reflection of $x1$ about $-x2$ is simply:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This can be intuited by drawing the line $y = -x$ and seeing what happens when you rotate basis vectors around it. You got it from here?

Comment: I'm still not following completely. When I do matrix multiplication of these two matrices the two values in my column two need to be switched to get the given answer.